# How can I add Dropbox component to React Native application?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dropbox, dropbox-api

I tried to implement it through [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser#android) but was not able to do it because of the crappy documentation. Can you please help with this?

Answer (score 1):

there is open source sample project for `dropbox` implementation in react native

check this https://github.com/thanhtungdp/react-native-dropbox